# What is the Ask Ubuntu Classroom and how can I participate?

Tags: discussion, chat, tutorials

#### What?

The Ask Ubuntu classroom is a series of free sessions where an Expert teaches attendees some of their skills in a variety of fields.

#### Where?

The sessions are going to be held in the [Classroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/663/ask-ubuntu-classroom) on [Ask Ubuntu Chat](http://chat.askubuntu.com)

#### When?

This post is to organise the calendar. If you want to hold a session, add your name and the topic to the calendar, and let one of the Moderators know to Schedule the Event in the Ask Ubuntu Chat System.

---

### For Attendees

If you plan to attend a session, please register for the event. Transcripts of all events will be available to the public afterwards.

Take a look at the [chat schedule](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/663/ask-ubuntu-classroom?tab=schedule) for estimated durations. Sessions may run over the alloted time, but we expect them to be fairly close.

---

### For Speakers

If you want to hold your own session, please come and talk to one of the [moderators](https://askubuntu.com/about) in the [Ask Ubuntu chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

We expect sessions to take between 30 and 120 minutes. You should make sure your material fits in that time-frame. You should also be [familiar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) with our chat system. Sessions should generally relate to the topic of Ubuntu in the same way as questions on the site should. You can of course hold session on topics such as Inkscape or Perl, but they should assume Ubuntu users as the target audience.

---

### For organisers

Please discuss organisational issues here:

- [Ask Ubuntu Classroom Organizers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/705/ask-ubuntu-classroom-organizers?tab=general)

Keep in mind that you can just leave messages. It's much easier to read than a huge comment thread on this question :-)

Answer (score 14):

### Scheduled Sessions

- #### DVCS, why you should be doing it.

  An introduction to the ideology of [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control), various workflows, comparison of: [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)), [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial), and [Bazaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_(software)) - and how to get started with each. Time permitting this will also cover connecting to [LaunchPad](http://launchpad.net), [Github](http://github.com), and [Google Code](http://code.google.com)

  TBD - [Marco Ceppi](https://askubuntu.com/users/41/marco-ceppi) - **[register for this event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/663/ask-ubuntu-classroom?tab=schedule)**

### Past Sessions

- #### [Introduction to Computer Programming using Python](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/663/conversation/introduction-to-computer-programming-using-python-3rd-july-2011-1800-utc)

  This is a gentle introduction into writing computer programs in Python. It starts from the basics of writing and running the "Hello World" program and finishes with your first simple GTK application. After the session, you will be able to write applications for the Ubuntu Desktop.

  Sunday, 3rd of July, [18:00 UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=Ask%20Ubuntu%20Classroom:%20Introduction%20to%20Computer%20Programming%20using%20Python&iso=20110703T18&ah=2) - [Stefano Palazzo](https://askubuntu.com/users/1067/stefano-palazzo) - **[Transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/663/conversation/introduction-to-computer-programming-using-python-3rd-july-2011-1800-utc)**  ([Online](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/663/conversation/introduction-to-computer-programming-using-python-3rd-july-2011-1800-utc) / [PDF](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/240188/python_class.pdf))
- #### [The Basics of Packaging on Ubuntu (Packaging: Part 1)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/663/conversation/the-basics-of-packaging-on-ubuntu-packaging-part-1)

  This is a step-by-step procedure for beginners to create packages (.deb installers) on Ubuntu.  Utilizing steps in the how-to provided on the Ubuntu Wiki, this guide is to help explain those steps so a normal user can use them, but it also addresses steps outside those that are defined in the how-to which are critical to creating a .deb for Ubuntu, including helping beginners understand how to create the basic structure for creating a .deb installer/package.  This will focus on the end result of a standalone .deb installer, and does **not** cover uploading to a launchpad PPA, does **not** cover creating a PPA-compatible version of a .deb, and does **not** explain incorporating the .deb into Ubuntu, Launchpad, or other systems. (There will be other Packaging classroom sessions which will cover these items)

  Saturday, 9th of July, [18:00 UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=The+Basics+of+Packaging+on+Ubuntu&iso=20110709T14&p1=97&ah=1&am=30) - [The Evil Phoenix](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/the-evil-phoenix) - **[Transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/663/conversation/the-basics-of-packaging-on-ubuntu-packaging-part-1)**
- #### [Ubuntu Packaging for Launchpad PPAs (Packaging: Part 2)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/663/conversation/ubuntu-packaging-for-launchpad-ppas-packaging-part-2)

  This is the second part of the packaging sessions, specifically regarding the packaging process and the uploading of packages to Launchpad PPAs.  This session does not cover the steps outlined in the first session, and does not outline the process for getting your packages considered for addition to the standard Ubuntu repositories.  This session strictly continues from the first session, elaborating on how to upload to a Launchpad PPA and allow for your packages to be modified there.

  Saturday, 9th of July, [19:30 UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=Ubuntu+Packaging+for+Launchpad+PPAs&iso=20110709T1530&p1=97&ah=1) - [The Evil Phoenix](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/the-evil-phoenix) - **[Transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/663/conversation/ubuntu-packaging-for-launchpad-ppas-packaging-part-2)**

### Proposed Sessions

- Sed and Awk
- Introduction to Bash scripting
- Introduction to Perl scripting
- Getting up and running with LAMP on Ubuntu Server
- Introduction to SQL and MySQL Database Management
- Introduction to Video Editing using OpenShot
- Introduction to Ardour
- Working with virtual machines
- Basic 3D modelling with Blender
- Working with the Gimp
- Setting up Squid (proxy server)
- Introduction to C++ programming with Qt
- Compiling the Linux kernel
- Introduction to the NGINX Webserver

Comment: A session on packaging would be *awesome*.

Comment: Perl...? Okay, that one should be good :)

Comment: @George its proposed, we actually need someone to lead that :P  Are you offering to lead it?  xD

Comment: @The: If I taught Perl, people would be climbing up walls and scratching chalkboards.

Comment: @George well then we'll need to find someone... what we'll probably do is find some perl experts on stackoverflow or something and have them show up ;)

Comment: @The: There's [Larry Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall)...

Comment: Note to all:  The Packaging sessions are subject to date, time, and content changes, so please check the descriptions for them often.  (6/30/2011)

Comment: The problem with most of these is they are very GUI oriented. It would be hard to run a text only classroom on them

Comment: Packaging is understandably going to be mostly text and console based.  Bash scripting and Perl scripting are text based as well, and SQL and MySQL Database Management can be taught from a CLI perspective.  A majority of the rest are GUI-oriented, though.

Comment: @TheEvilPheonix That's why I'm excited to see what people come up with as a solution :)

Comment: @Marco: A solution for the CLI-based sessions or the GUI-based ones?

Comment: @George: a solution for the GUI based ones.

Comment: @The: Are you looking for some sort of screencasting tool?

Comment: maybe we should move this long comment thread into [it's own chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/705/ask-ubuntu-classroom-organizers?tab=general)

Comment: (last comment) @George I am not, the sessions i'm teaching are all going to be taught from a command line basis

Comment: why this have died? :/