# Organising "classrooms" for 10th birthday celebrations

Tags: discussion, community, 10th-anniversary

This follows up on [How should we celebrate 10 years of Ask Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19187/how-should-we-celebrate-10-years-of-ask-ubuntu). The [answer by jokerdino](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19192/527764) suggesting [Ask Ubuntu Classrooms](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1568/what-is-the-ask-ubuntu-classroom-and-how-can-i-participate) was very popular so this post is an attempt to start organising it. I have also [posted](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19236/527764) about making a banner or other means of notifying people about events.

---

The idea is to have learning sessions (most likely in chat) about things we can do in Ubuntu, around the time of Ask Ubuntu's 10th anniversary in October.

Please **post an answer here** to

- **Request** a session about something you would like to learn
- **Offer** a session you would like to teach

If you can offer a session that has been requested, it may be sufficient to comment on the request, rather than posting a new answer.

---

**Note**: Other ideas may also be taken forward. Everyone is hereby encouraged to post on meta or [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) (feel free to ping me) about implementing any other celebration ideas.

Answer (score 14):

#### Request

I would like to learn about writing a new ***gnome-shell extension from scratch*** as [jokerdino suggested](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19187/how-should-we-celebrate-10-years-of-ask-ubuntu/19192#19192).

Shell extensions are used quite often and are very useful. Even the [official wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial) is not completed yet, and there aren't many good resources available for this. I think *Learning by building a extension* will be fun and insightful.

Answer (score 14):

#### Offer

I am willing to do a very beginner level introduction to command line and basic file permissions, if it is of interest

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu and would love to learn this

Comment: Although only experience Ubuntu users care about Ubuntu's anniversary, I think this would be a great idea.

Comment: It seems that U&L has covered this fairly well: [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/80216), [Execute vs Read bit – How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/80216), [What are the different ways to set file permissions, etc, on GNU/Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/80216), and more.  Do you believe that AU needs a separate copy of that information?  Is there something you would add for Ubuntu that isn’t already in the U&L answers?  If so, please add it there.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' the idea is to give an interactive lesson about the topic, not write an answer about it

Comment: I tend to use line commands only when necessary, i.e. checking kernel version after an update. It would be useful for me to have a primer when I do need to use these things.  File permissions like chmod, and whatever 777 means etc, and why its there - sounds useful.

Answer (score 10):

**Offer**

Learning by doing: How to host a package in PPA and Snapcraft.

Comment: This is awesome! I was going to ask for this as a "request" but kept procrastinating. Thank you for reading my mind!

Comment: Hi! The lessons are now being scheduled. Please check out [the new meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19320/scheduling-lessons-for-10th-anniversary-celebration-classroom) and post an answer to schedule your lesson, if you are still willing to teach it - thank you!

Answer (score 9):

#### Request

I would like some tips on using Vim efficiently and doing clever things with it.

Answer (score 8):

### Request

Setting up regular backups like using rsync

Comment: I've recently been fiddling with an rsync backup script, so I feel I could give some hints and tips to general CLI usage of rsync. However, I'm not sure I would feel comfortable by hosting an entire session by myself, but maybe I could supplement someone: 1) Teaching the graphical rsync interface or 2) As an addon to an existing CLI session. @Zanna what do you think? :-)

Comment: Sounds awesome @ArturMeinild

Answer (score 5):

#### Request

> [I would like a lesson on how to use the perl rename command.](https://old.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/i5x164/ask_ubuntu_10_year_birthday_celebrations/g0txxa4/)

-- Reddit user [SpecificHat](https://old.reddit.com/user/SpecificHat)

Comment: I nominate [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) to give that lesson :D

Comment: @Zanna I'm happy to share what I know. I might need some help organizing it though since i) I'm not very good at organizing and ii) I really don't have much free time these days. If it's just a question of churning out a few rename examples or fielding questions from interested users, then I can do it with no preparation. If I need to create some sort of course, I will have to ask for help on what it should cover. It basically comes down to "Here are some fancy things you can do with PCRE regexes".

Comment: Ah. [Eliah](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) is at _least_ as knowledgeable about this as I am, most probably more, and has been known to produce a book on any given subject at the slightest provocation. Maybe I'll ask him!

Comment: @terdon anything goes! Examples and/or Q&A would be great. I could come up with some "and how do I do such-and-such?" type stuff or whatever else would help and participate. It will be done in chat I guess. As for organisation, we will take care of it. But, it's totally cool if you are too busy, I *really* get that!

Comment: If it's something I can do off the top of my head (it probably is, unless you need some clear structure), then it should be fine in October.

Comment: @terdon sorry not to have followed up earlier. The lessons are now being scheduled via [this meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19320/scheduling-lessons-for-10th-anniversary-celebration-classroom). Please post an answer to schedule your lesson if you are still willing to teach it :)

Comment: @Zanna ah, crud. I'm actually flying back to London on that Saturday, and this week looks like I'm going to have an insane amount of work. I might try for Sunday but I can't commit right now.

Comment: @terdon it's the week after, or basically whenever you feel like it :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Request

Precautions and safety measures to be taken while running commands (that could affect our system).

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice lesson for systemd. Like make own target or service system-wide or for user associated with udev.

Answer (score 1):

#### Request

I would like to learn about using Windows and Android programs on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

#### Request

Tricks to speed up Ubuntu ⚡⚡.