# Scheduling lessons for 10th anniversary celebration classroom

Tags: discussion, community, 10th-anniversary

Oops time passed.

I have created a public chat room for the 10th anniversary lessons:

#### [Join the Classroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/classroom)

All lessons will be held there. This post is for scheduling the lessons.

**If you would like to give a lesson, please post an answer with the topic for your lesson and the provisional timing (please give the UTC time, or if you are giving your local time, give the time zone).**

**The actual date of the anniversary seems to be 10/10/2020 which is a Saturday, so I suggest lessons should be scheduled any time between Friday 9th October and Sunday 18th October.**

---

Anyone giving a lesson will be made an owner of the room. This provides some useful privileges:

- Add/remove events in the room's schedule
- Freeze the room to get everyone's attention (prevents anyone from adding messages)
- Move messages to other rooms
- Control feeds to the room
- Read deleted messages

Mods will do our best to support. I will try to attend all the lessons if I can expect to be awake when they take place.

If you want to offer a lesson that has not been mentioned yet, please feel free to go ahead and post it here in the schedule. If you prefer to gauge community interest first, or you want to request a lesson rather than offer one, you can post [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19218/organising-classrooms-for-10th-birthday-celebrations) or just make a new meta question about it.

#### [Sign up for scheduled classes here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/113418/classroom?tab=schedule)

Thanks a lot to anyone participating!

Comment: I suggest to bookmark the transcript of lessons held in chat room and link it back to the respective answers here.

Comment: @Pandya Great idea - done! Also added the bookmarks to the Happy Anniversary post with the single post schedule

Answer (score 13):

#### Beginner-level introduction to command line (Part 1*)

Sunday 11th October - 15:00-16:00 UTC

---

<sub>*Haven't prepared Part 2 yet though O.O...</sub>

---

In case you missed it: [lesson transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/beginner-level-introduction-to-command-line-part-1)

Comment: i.e. Sunday 11th October 2020 20:30 (8:30 PM) - 21:30 (9:30 PM) Indian Standard Time (IST) https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html

Comment: Obviously the IST time is the most important ;)

Answer (score 10):

#### Introduction to software installation

Saturday October, 10 14:00-16:00 UTC

---

In case you missed it: [lesson transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/introduction-to-software-installation)

Comment: Is it about .deb packages, apt, synaptic, compiling software and other related stuff?

Comment: It's about all those topics, and there is also some interesting material that hasn't been posted at Ask Ubuntu that I wanted to showcase.

Comment: Can you bookmark the chat lesson transcript and post a link here?

Comment: @Pandya [Software installation lesson transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55785317#55785317)

Answer (score 8):

#### Beginner-level introduction to command line (Part 2*)

Sunday 18th October, 15:00 - 16:00 UTC

---

<sub>* actually it's still Part 1 as we didn't finish it, but I can just call it Part 2 and nobody will ever know I still haven't prepared the real Part 2 yet ^_^</sub>

---

In case you missed it: [lesson transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/beginner-level-introduction-to-command-line-part-2).

Answer (score 8):

### Introduction to SSH, Rsync and Cron

Sunday 25th of October, 16:00 - 17:00 UTC

#### Agenda

- Basic SSH usage
- Basic Rsync CLI usage
- Basic usage of Rsync with cron
- Using SSHFS to mount remote folders
- Taste of advanced Rsync script (if there is time)

---

In case you missed it: [lesson transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/introduction-to-ssh-rsync-and-cron)

Answer (score 8):

### Beginner level introduction to command line (part 3*)

Sunday 25th October 2020, 14:30-15:30 UTC

---

<sub>* It's technically still part 1 - I guess we'll be doing this until Ask Ubuntu's next birthday...</sub>

---

In case you missed it: [lesson transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/113418/ask-ubuntu-classroom?tab=conversations)

Answer (score 5):

### SSH, Rsync and Cron - Continuation, clarification and questions

Sunday 1st of November, 16:00 - 17:00 UTC

---

In case you missed it: [lesson transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/ssh-rsync-and-cron-continuation-clarification-and-questions)

Answer (score 4):

### Beginner level introduction to command line (part 4)

Sunday 1st November 2020, 14:30-15:30 UTC

---

In case you missed it: [lesson transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/beginner-level-introduction-to-command-line-part-4)