# Happy 10th anniversary to Ask Ubuntu!

Tags: discussion, community, 10th-anniversary

Ask Ubuntu was launched on 10/10/2010, so it's now just about 10 years old!

To celebrate we are running some workshops / lessons in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/classroom). So far this is [the schedule](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19320/scheduling-lessons-for-10th-anniversary-celebration-classroom):

---

### Introduction to software installation

#### by [karel](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel)

Saturday 10th October 2020
14:00-16:00 UTC

Catch up: view the lesson [transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/introduction-to-software-installation)

---

### Beginner level introduction to command line (part 1)

#### by [Zanna](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna)

Sunday 11th October 2020
15:00-16:00 UTC

Catch up: view the lesson [transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/beginner-level-introduction-to-command-line-part-1)

---

### Beginner level introduction to command line (part 2)

#### by [Zanna](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna)

Sunday 18th October 2020
15:00-16:00 UTC

Catch up: view the lesson [transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/beginner-level-introduction-to-command-line-part-2)

---

### Beginner level introduction to command line (part 3)

#### by [Zanna](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna)

Sunday 25th October 2020
14:30-15:30 UTC

Catch up: view the lesson [transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/beginner-level-introduction-to-command-line-part-3)

---

### Introduction to SSH, Rsync and Cron

#### by [Artur Meinild](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/1066942/artur-meinild)

Sunday 25th of October
16:00 - 17:00 UTC

#### Agenda

- Basic SSH usage
- Basic Rsync CLI usage
- Basic usage of Rsync with cron
- Using SSHFS to mount remote folders
- Taste of advanced Rsync script (if there is time)

Catch up: view the lesson [transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/introduction-to-ssh-rsync-and-cron)

---

### Beginner level introduction to command line (part 4)

#### by [Zanna](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna)

Sunday 1st November 2020
14:30-15:30 UTC

Catch up: view the lesson [transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/beginner-level-introduction-to-command-line-part-4)

---

### SSH, Rsync and Cron - Continuation, clarification and questions

#### by [Artur Meinild](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/1066942/artur-meinild)

Sunday 1st November 2020
16:00-17:00 UTC

Catch up: view the lesson [transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/conversation/ssh-rsync-and-cron-continuation-clarification-and-questions)

---

#### [Join the classroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113418/classroom)

#### [Sign up for scheduled lessons](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/113418/classroom?tab=schedule)

Please feel free to offer or request more lessons [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19218/organising-classrooms-for-10th-birthday-celebrations) or by making a new meta post.

---

Also:

#### [What's your Ubuntu story?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19335/whats-your-ubuntu-story)

---

I will add any other celebration events to this post.

If you are organising an event, you may like to post an answer here to describe what you are doing and allow people to engage in comments. You could also make another meta question. If your event only needs to be a meta post (like some of the ideas posted on [How should we celebrate 10 years of Ask Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19187/how-should-we-celebrate-10-years-of-ask-ubuntu)), go ahead and post your meta post and I'll add a link to it here. If you need any kind of help organising or getting involved, you can comment, ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), make a new meta post, or employ whatever alternative strategy appeals to you :)

---

Thanks to [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija) for organising [the banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJAbc.jpg)! Catija also mentioned that she has some Stack Overflow stickers to send to people giving lessons :D

Comment: I'm glad that there's a banner! But I wish it could have been a bit bigger.

Comment: [Proposal of Ubuntu site on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716) and [Ask Ubuntu launch news on OMG! Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ask-ubuntu-stack-exchange-site-out-of-beta-new-awesome-domain).

Comment: Please add the photo of the banner in this post.

Comment: Sounds amazing, however I am worried about chat.stackexchange being the platform for this. Chats are not browsed by search engines, so whatever useful information appears there, it never gets out to the outside world. So I'd say, it has smaller impact to Linux community than it could have. My personal opinion, something like Youtube or Twitch might be more appropriate. There one also have a *(very small)* chance to attract occasional people through recommendations system.

Comment: @Hi-Angel the impact is meant to be on the participant. The lessons are interactive. We have a whole site for producing knowledge for the wider Linux community. If anyone learns anything in these lessons, they can perhaps become a distributor of that knowledge. But I'll be happy if they just enjoy it too.

Answer (score 21):

#### Not an event, just a look back on how the site design changed over the time.

Click on the image to get the full page on [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org). This post was made possible because of the big cached page library Wayback Machine has.

---

- Ubuntu - Stack Exchange (2010)

  [image: Ubuntu - Stack Exchange (2010)]
- Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange (2011)

  [image: Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange (2011)]
- Ask Ubuntu (2012)

  [image: Ask Ubuntu (2012)]
- Ask Ubuntu (2013) (Somewhat redesigned)

  [image: Ask Ubuntu (2013)]
- Ask Ubuntu (2014) (Tour time calculated, i.e., "Take the tour" was changed to "Take the 2 minute tour")

  [image: Ask Ubuntu (2014)]
- Ask Ubuntu (2015) (No tour without signing up or logging in)

  [image: Ask Ubuntu (2015)]
- Ask Ubuntu (2016)

  [image: Ask Ubuntu (2016)]
- Ask Ubuntu (2017) (Top bar redesigned)

  [image: Ask Ubuntu (2017)]
- Ask Ubuntu (2018) (Massive redesign and the emergence of responsive design across the Stack Exchange network: [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/468333))

  [image: Ask Ubuntu (2018)]
- Ask Ubuntu (2019) (Introductory banner redesigned and color "Sign Up" and "Log in"  button changed to match with site color)

  [image: Ask Ubuntu (2019)]
- Ask Ubuntu (2020) (On its birthday!!!)

  [image: Ask Ubuntu (2020)]

Comment: Nice idea, thanks for posting this!

Comment: What changed? :pepeThink:

Comment: Frankly, I like 2017 look the best.