# Let's organize some chat workshops

Tags: discussion, featured, community

Some of y'all may remember that way back in the mists of time, [we celebrated Ask Ubuntu's 10th birthday with some chat-based workshops](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19334/happy-10th-anniversary-to-ask-ubuntu). That was pretty cool.

The other day [Artur Meinild](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/1066942/artur-meinild) [mentioned](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65366360) that he would be interested in running a workshop (on using Docker at home) in the near future (reminding me that I had said I would some day do the vaguely planned second series of my command line basics sessions O_O).

The upcoming LTS release (which always brings more people to Ask Ubuntu) seems like a good excuse to organize workshops.

So, does anyone have any ideas for chat workshops or other fun activities?

Comment: I really hope others could find the time to engage in this - I think it would be a good and enlightening way to engage the community. 

Comment: "The upcoming LTS release... seems like a good excuse to organize workshops." ... Uh, you know there's [a much, much bigger reason](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-20th-anniversary-party-planning/43174) (that's also similar to the last time's reason) coming up (though we might be starting a bit earlier)

Comment: @muru Let's make it a 20 anniversary pre-party then! 

Comment: @ArturMeinild [yay!](https://tenor.com/Zk7Z.gif)

Comment: @ArturMeinild  I'm in!

Answer (score 7):

As @Zanna mentioned, I would like to arrange a session on using Docker Engine (Community Edition) on home servers.

I imagine the following agenda for the session(s):

- Introduction to and installing Docker
- The basics: Using Docker CLI
- The basics: Docker Networking
- Tip #1: Create a script to start your containers
- Case #1: ??? *(Open to suggestions - running your first container)*
- Tip #2: Use persistent volumes (bind mounts)
- Case #2: Install a Docker Web GUI (Portainer)
- Tip #3: Using Docker Compose
- Case #3: Install a Docker Compose Web GUI (Dockge)

I think this workshop could very well be held over several 1 hour sessions (maybe 1 week in between), to allow for questions etc.

Also, there is a practicality in that this session should be held after the Docker repos are updated to support Ubuntu 24.04. I think this usually takes 2-4 weeks after the LTS release, so we'll have to see and arrange the session as soon as it becomes available.

If anyone have questions or suggestions for the agenda, please post them here as comments, and I'll try and take it into account for the session.

Comment: About the Docker repos thing: Ubuntu does package Docker (now [only as a snap](https://snapcraft.io/docker), I suppose) and that option is what gets shown in the Server installation, so I'd suggesting using that for the first few sessions until Docker repos are updated, and then have a session on removing the snap and using the repo instead (and the several reasons why one might want to do that)

Comment: @muru That would be a possibility. I'm not keen on spending too much time explaining Docker as a Snap because: 1) I've never run it that way, 2) I prefer the other way. But I'll try and see if I can work in something about the difference between the default Snap installation and the custom repo installation I'll demonstrate. And I'll definitely also cover removing the Snap version. 

Comment: Maybe than I finally check what docker is and what it is good for 

Comment: @nobody I'll happily demonstrate that for you if you attend. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild this will be fun.

Comment: @nobody Totally!

Comment: If my schedule permits, count me in! I’m game for a better understanding of Docker.

Answer (score 5):

I could do a session on setting up zigbee2mqtt + homeassistant in Docker if there's any interest in that.

Would be a good and natural follow up to Arthur Meinild's Docker presentation :)

- Setting up HomeAssistant in Docker
- Setting up zigbee2mqtt
- Adding devices
- A bit on automation perhaps

Comment: I would be extremely interested in such a session, since I've been thinking about using Homeassistant, but never got around to setting it up. 

Comment: Great! You have to do a good job of teaching people docker then, so we can use that for the deployment ;)

Comment: Yes, I think it'll work out 